# One to six, do you know?

Tags: riddle, word

> One two three, I am yet to open,
>   one two four, fix me now,
>   Four five six, when you ready come and ?,

What is this problem ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is

> BUDGET. B=1 U=2 D=3 G=4 E=5 T=6

One two three, I am yet to open,

> BUD, not a flower yet

one two four, fix me now,

> BUG, as in code

Four five six, when you ready come and ?,

> GET, like come and get me.

Comment: That is brilliant! Good job!

Comment: ok +50 bounty tomorrow..

Comment: How did you do the correlation between the numbers and the letters? it would be interesting to tell us.

Answer (score 2):

Partial(Which could be possible wrong)

> I think these are the song titles

Here are they

One two three, I am yet to open

> Not sure..

one two four, fix me now

> [Fix me now](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Garbage:Fix_Me_Now) by Garbage

Four five six, when you ready come and ?,

> [Come and get me by Selena Gomez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_%26_Get_It_%28Selena_Gomez_song%29)

So

> May be we need to take the letters out of these which may give **_ _ _ GABENA**

Comment: The only music I can hear when reading this puzzle is the theme song of freddy...getting chills.

Comment: Haha..  You just made me watch it again :D

Comment: ok nice , but not so complicated question it simple level..